# Is there a callBack to SetContentView in Android?

Tags: android, callback, view

Is there any callBack to setContentView in Android, since i'm doing a heavy operation right after setContentView line, and it seems to skip that setContentView.

So i was thinking of moving the heavyOperation to the callBack of setContentView.

Thanks

EDIT:

Pseudo Code:

AudioRecord Finishes
SetContentView(1) //To show a "Processing" screen with no buttons
FFT analysis
SetContentView(2) //On FFT analysis DONE.

In my case "SetContentView(1)" NEVER occurs.

EDIT # 2:
I did the heavy operation in another Thread, and used Handler to send a Message after heavy operation finishes to treat it as a callBack.

Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: `setContentView` will never be skipped. Do you mean delayed?

Comment: Yes, probably delayed.
is there a way around?

Comment: In Java lines of a function aren't ever skipped.

Comment: I know, but the screen isn't rendered.

Comment: When this FFT is happening and where ? Show us the code ?

Comment: see the pseudo code above

Comment: Don't do the heavy operation in onCreate(), or even on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No callback for the `setContentView`.

If you are doing network operation then you can use the `AsyncTask` for this.

If you are doing any more heavy operation and want to update the UI then you can do that using the `Service` and `BroadCastReceiver`.

For this you have to make your own callback using the `interface`.

Comment: No i'm doing FFT of a sound file.
After recording sound, i want to change the screen with no buttons,
then perform FFT analysis, and change the view back again after FFT is done.

But in my case it skips the "No button" screen and moves directly to the end of FFT analysis screen

Answer (score 2):

`heavy work` should be done in `asynk tasks` or as a `service` or on `other threads`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do any heavy calculations on the main UI thread where `onCreate()` and such are run.

What happens that the first `setContentView()` posts a "layout and draw" message to the UI thread message queue. Then your calculation blocks the UI thread, preventing messages in the queue from being processed. The second `setContentView()` posts another message to the queue. When the control eventually returns to the message loop, both messages are processed and you'll get the layout set up by the last call to `setContentView()`.

For heavy computations, use a separate thread. For example, an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) make threading easier.

Answer (score 1):

My hack.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
setContentView(layoutResID); // This posts some messages to message queue.
handler.post(new Runnable() { // Post another message at the end.
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Called after layout has changed.
        // If you want to skip some more works (like transitions),
        // call another handler.post() here.
    }
});
```

To see what happens, set a break point at the line `Message msg = queue.next();` in Looper.loop() may help.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a quite similar problem a day ago, but I figured it out. (I know your problem is solved, just offering a different approach which doesn't require a handler or callback.

**Most Suitable for running U.I. functions :**
If you need to do something like this :`runTask() then
setContentView()  (or any other ui function)` you can run the task on different thread by using `AsyncTask` or you can set a timer for when the task is completed (if your task takes a certain time), the User Interface functions will be called.
But since the Timer class, runs the functions on a different thread, you can not run the `setContentView()` inside it. So you can use a `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)` method inside the overloaded `run()` function of Timer class. You just need to define a function that returns a runnable. Define your Ui operations in the runnable action.

Hope it helps someone.